# Boost Beast, how to supply login credentials

Tags: c++, http, boost-beast

I am trying to send an http request to a device on our network that requires credentials.
For example in a webbrowser the request that works would be:

http://mylogin:myPassword@10.11.2.118/axis-cgi/virtualinput/activate.cgi?schemaversion=1&port=1

However, I can't figure out how to put the login and password information in using boost beast.

I create the request as such:

```
  // host = mylogin:myPassword@10.11.2.118 does not resolve
  // host = 10.11.2.118 resolves but I get an authentication error from the device due to no username and password
  auto results = resolver.resolve(host, port)
   ...
   //Do the connecting
   ...

  http::request<http::string_body> req{http::verb::get, path, 11};
  req.set(http::field::host, host);
  req.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);
  req.set(http::field::content_type, "application/json");
  req.set(http::field::accept, "vdn.dac.v1");
```

Is there a field in the request I can use?

Update:
I found the following library which supports basic and Digest authentication using Boost Beast: https://github.com/RAvenGEr/simple-beast-client.  Using that library I can perform the request to the above URL.  It is more complicated than I would like though.

Update:
I switch to using libcurl which handles authentication for you (I can put the url I supplied in directly and allow Digest authentication).

Comment: With recommending https://github.com/RAvenGEr/simple-beast-client you and especially RAvenGEr (author of the lib) help me a lot. Thanks everybody and @VinnieFalco for the Beast lib too. Mind that Simple Beast Client needs to define ENABLE_DIGEST for the lib compilation to allow the authentication as above.

Answer (score 2):

You need to encode the string mylogin:myPassword to base64 format, then prepend it with "Basic " like in the following:

```
req.set(http::field::authorization, "Basic bXlsb2dpbjpteVBhc3N3b3Jk");
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
http::request<http::string_body> req; // defaults to HTTP/1.1
req.method(http::verb::get);
req.target("mylogin:myPassword@10.11.2.118/axis-cgi/virtualinput/activate.cgi?schemaversion=1&port=1");
...
```

Comment: That sets the target correctly, however it appears that the browser uses those parameters to do Digest authentication so changing the target this way still results in unauthorized access.

Comment: Well you have to read the RFC which describes HTTP Digest Authentication (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2617) and make sure you follow the protocol. Beast doesn't do this for you, it is up to you to read and write the appropriate HTTP messages.

Comment: I was hoping Beast did do it for me, but you are right it doesn't so I switch to using libcurl which handles if for you.

Comment: Thank you @VinnieFalco with your Boost Beast and with RAvenGEr's simple beast client I was able to get it. The clarification for enabling digest auth really matters.